# Linq to get difference of two listviews and put it in third in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, listview

I have two list views which have same data but differing in the number of records. I want to get the non-matching listviewitems in third list view. I have using the following code but it is not helping. The variables x and y are making problem.

```
var list1Source = lvFace.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();
var list2Source = lvDBdata.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();

lvDataToUpload = list1Source.Where(
    (x => list2Source.All(y => y.Text != x.Text));
```

Comment: Does any answer help? I edited my answer as well

Comment: And I think you want the non matching elements from both the lists right ?

Comment: what is the error message when you hover the cursor over the error?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [LINQ Except method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var lvExcept1 = list1Source.Except(list2Source);
var lvExcept2 = list2Source.Except(list1Source);

lvDataToUpload = lvExcept1.Union(lvExcept2);
```

But you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for your `ListViewItem` class. If there is no option to do this (`ListViewItem` is Windows Forms class, not yours), you can define your own equality comparer:

```
public class ListViewItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<ListViewItem>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<ListViewItem>.Equals(ListViewItem x, ListViewItem y)
    {
        return (x.Text == y.Text);
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<ListViewItem>.GetHashCode(ListViewItem obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return 0;

        return obj.Text.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And final code is:

```
var lvExcept1 = list1Source.Except(list2Source, new ListViewItemComparer());
var lvExcept2 = list2Source.Except(list1Source, new ListViewItemComparer());

lvDataToUpload = lvExcept1.Union(lvExcept2);
```

Comment: ListViewItem class isn't the OP's to change - and this won't get the full difference, only things that are in list1 but not list2. What about things in list2 but not list1?

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, I have edited the answer, must be correct.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ doesn't have a "set difference" operator itself... but you can use `Except` twice:

```
var list1Text = list1Source.Select(x => x.Text);
var list2Text = list2Source.Select(x => x.Text);
var difference = list1Text.Except(list2Text)
                          .Concat(list2Text.Except(list1Text))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: @user2955299 *Show me teh codez*... Suggest you buy Jon's book if you need help working out the basics.

Comment: @user2955299: I'm sure it doesn't talk about "system.fun". Please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have uploaded the screenshots to the dropbox.

[Errors](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nw6vc1zxle5qx8o/AAAraLMHeFeezw6oHrHYrV-Ta?dl=0)

Comment: @user2955299: Look at the code in your screenshot - it isn't the code in my post. I'm using `list1Source.Select` - you're using `lvFace.Select`. Yes, if you use completely different code to the code in my answer, you *will* get errors...

Comment: My mistake... How I will convert difference variable to ListView?

Comment: @user2955299: Have you done any research yet? Stack Overflow isn't about spoonfeeding complete code to avoid you having to do any work. How do you normally provide data to a ListView?

Comment: I don't want to ask such questions but in my question I was directly using listviews but you are using variables.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am still unable to convert the variable difference to listview. Kindly help....!!!

Comment: @user2955299: Have you tried using `ListView.Items`? You could iterate over the `List<string>` and add each string to the items, or use another `Select` projection and `ToArray` (instead of `ToList`) to create a `ListViewItem[]` and call `AddRange`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
listIntersection = list1Source.Intersect(list2Source); // Gets matching elements
listUnion = list1Source.Union(list2Source); // Gets all elements

lvDataToUpload = listUnion.Except(listIntersection);
```

Comment: That will find the intersection, not the difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please check now is it fine... I was editing it while being downvoted :)

Comment: @user2955299: "is not working" is a hopelessly vague description of the problem. It would also help if you would state which version of Visual Studio you're using, and which version of .NET your app targets.